# Difference Between DictionaryBase and Dictionary<Tkey,Tvalue>

Tags: c#, .net, collections

Can anyone please tell me the difference between `DictionaryBase` and generic `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, except that `DictionaryBase` is an abstract class! Both of them are strongly typed and I read somewhere that generic classes are better than non-generic ones in performance and should be preferred, so what is the exact use of `DictionaryBase` then?
Both the classes are almost same!

Any kind of help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dictionarybase is base class implementing the non generic IDictionary interface while Dictionary is the generic version of a dictionary implementing the generic IDictionary interface. Use of generics is preferred over non generics.

I think this would be more helpful [When to use generics?](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBYQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fms172181.aspx&ei=BKQlTYG4AsaAOrX8_OkC&usg=AFQjCNFLb_QPys5n70rzPoIw3EGUOfKu6A&sig2=D7TUHqs5a8GeC7o0gFLfBQ)

> Using generic collections is generally recommended, because you gain
>   the immediate benefit of type safety without having to derive from a
>   base collection type and implement type-specific members. Generic
>   collection types also generally perform better than the corresponding
>   nongeneric collection types (and better than types that are derived
>   from nongeneric base collection types) when the collection elements
>   are value types, because with generics there is no need to box the
>   elements.

Also go through, [Introduction to Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x6a29h6%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

> Generic classes and methods combine reusability, type safety and
>   efficiency in a way that their non-generic counterparts cannot.
>   Generics are most frequently used with collections and the methods
>   that operate on them. Version 2.0 of the .NET Framework class library
>   provides a new namespace, System.Collections.Generic, which contains
>   several new generic-based collection classes. It is recommended that
>   all applications that target the .NET Framework 2.0 and later use the
>   new generic collection classes instead of the older non-generic
>   counterparts

Comment: Both the classes are strongly typed.. and also derive from interface. Except DictionaryBase all the classes in System.Collections, I guess aren't type-specific!! So, the difference remains of only that they derive from different interfaces and that DictionaryBase is an abstract class.

Comment: Shouldn't the counterparts of generic classes in non-generic classes be made Obsolete then!!!!!

Comment: The generic IDictionary is a generic version of the non generic IDictionary. Generics promote type safety and efficiency.

Answer (score 5):

The reason the non-generic collection types are still in the .NET framework is largely for backwards compatibility.  Generally you should use the generic collection types whenever possible.

Comment: So, there's no actual use of DictionaryBase because of the presence of Generic Dictionary!!

Answer (score 1):

I just finished converting an old `DictionaryBase` class that was `IXmlSerializable` to generic `Dictionary(string, string)`.

The most painful difference is that for the generic `Dictionary<string, string>`, when I call `this[key]` for a key that does not exist, I get an exception stating the key does not exist.

On a `DictionaryBase` I get back `null` with no exception.  This was painful in my case because the system was full of code that did not check that the dictionary `ContainsKey` before trying to get the keys value.  It was made more painful by me assuming I messed something up with serialization.